# Replying to the notification with a 202-Accepted status

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, office365

i just have one question, How do i send a 202 - Accepted status code in my response to Microsoft Graph? Very new at this. Greetings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#change-notifications "Processing the change notification" is the part of the document where tells you to send a 202 status but i don't know what that means and how, i'm starting programming, so if someone could help me i'd appreciate it.

Comment: How do you send the other data?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with the other data?

Comment: The response to Microsoft Graph

Comment: I'm really messed up, this what i do, i subscripte to Microsoft graph just as the tutorial shows me, then i'm subscripting to an email change notification event, i'm using Ngrok, so everytime i get a new message my console in Azure Functions shows me the notification  and my cmd where i have my Ngrok shows me the HTTP request with the POST and the POST method with a 200 OK

Comment: Something like this  POST /api/MyPostSubscription 200 OK i use Microsoft Graph Explorer to see my subscription, delete or create a new one manually

Comment: Via HttpClient class or what?
Can you show me the chunk of code that do that request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233139/discussion-between-pee-and-emanuele).